# msxml selectnodes: namespace in text node

Tags: xpath, msxml

I have to following XML file:

```
<root xmlns="http://someurl/element" xmlns:text="http://someurl/text">
   <elements>
     <element>
       <Id>text:SOME_ID</Id>
       <!-- some other elements -->
     </element>
     <element>
       <!-- some other elements -->
       <reference>
          <link ref="text:SOME_ID" />
       </refernce>
     </element>
   </elements>
</root>
```

I want to select all child elements of the `elment` node which have the element `Id=text:SOME_ID` from the `reference` node. I want to do this in C++ by using the `selectNodes` method of the `IXMLDOMNode` object from msxml parser.

In the following exmaple I have the refence node selected in `pChild` and the `SelectionNamespaces` propetey set to `xmlns:n="http://someurl/element"`:

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pSelectedNodes =
    pChild->selectNodes("../../n:element[n:Id=n:link/@ref]/n:*");
__ASSERT(pSelectedNodes->length > 0)
```

This is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user141478: The problem is that you need to use an outer context inside an inner context filter. That's not posible in XPath 1.0. In XPath 2.0 you could do: `for $current in . return /*/*/n:element[n:Id eq $current/@ref]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `n:link/@ref` part of your XPath query is evaluated in the context of the element to which the conditional criteria are applied; in this case the `../../n:element`.
You can’t reference the overall context from within a conditional section; in other words, the context node is different inside and outside of the [square brackets].

I’m afraid you will have to extract the `pChild->selectSingleNode("n:link/@ref")->text` separately, and 'manually' insert that into your XPath query.